# Aggregate Queries: Can I return values where GROUP BY size is greater than 1?

Tags: apex, soql, query, aggregate

If I say

```
SELECT count(id), field_one__c, field_two__c 
   WHERE field_once__c > 1 AND field_two__c < 6 
   GROUP BY field_one__c, field_two__c
```

could I have it only return groups where the size is more than 1? I understand there is a `having` clause, but I do not believe it works with 'where'

Comment: What makes you say 'having' doesn't work with 'where'?  What's the actual query that's not working for you? Are you getting any errors when combining having and where?

Answer (score 4):

The `HAVING` clause works perfectly fine for this requirement. Just remember it goes after `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... HAVING count(Id) > 1
```